# how to get row value with ajax triggered by onchange dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I tried to update 1 row in table with ajax triggered by onchange dropdown, I succeed update data but it updating all data in my table.

so how I can get unique value (eg :User ID) to pass it from ajax to my php so i can update it only 1 row?

here's my code :

my table (transactions.php)

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>User ID</th>
         <th>Pengirim</th>
         <th>Jumlah Transfer</th>
         <th>Berita Acara</th>
         <th>Status</th>
         <th>Rincian</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <?php
         $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "select * from konf_transf order by tanggal desc limit 7 ");
         while($data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            ?>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <center><?php echo $data1['usr_id']; ?></center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center><?php echo $data1['nm_pengirim']; ?></center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>Rp. <?php echo number_format($data1['jmlh_transf'],0,'','.'); ?>,-</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center><?php echo $data1['berita_acara']; ?></center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center><?php echo $data1['status']; ?></center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>
               <select name="pilihstatus" id="pilihstatus" onchange="updatetransactions();">
                  <option value="Pilihan">Pilihan</option>
                  <option value="Sudah">Sudah</option>
                  <option value="Belum">Belum</option>
               </select>
            </center>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and here my ajax

```
function updatetransactions(){
  var id = $('select option:selected').val();  
$.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"updatestatustransaksi.php",
            data:"status="+id,
            success:function(data){
                alert('Successfully updated mysql database');
            }
        });
    }
```

my updatestatustransaksi.php

```
<?php
require_once("koneksi.php");
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "<script>alert('You must register an account first, we will redirect you to register page !'); window.location = 'registuser.php'</script>";
}
$dataupd = $_POST["status"];
$query   = mysqli_query($koneksi, "UPDATE `konf_transf` SET `status` = '$dataupd' WHERE `id` = '$penjualan_id'");
if ($query) {
    echo "<script>alert('Update Success.'); window.location = 'transactions.php' </script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Update Failure.'); window.location = 'transactions.php' </script>";
}
```

Comment: You have to include your `updatestatustransaksi.php` file

Comment: @LoganWayne updated

Comment: database not updating but i still got alert succeed update mysql database, I check post in console, it succeed passing parameter id & status

Comment: But the id and status have correct values?

Comment: sorry2 I didnt check the query, I update the query and its work update the data, thx Mr Logan Wayne

Comment: Sure thing. If an answer helped you, you can give back by accepting the answer or at least up-voting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I assume that you update all of your rows in your database, with no `WHERE` condition.</strike> In your script, lets also get the corresponding id of that row in your database.

Lets assign first the id for each table row:

```
while($data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        ?>
  <tr id="<?=($data1['user_id'])?>">
```

Then, lets change how you trigger your javascript. Lets first change the `<select>` field:

```
<select name="pilihstatus" id="pilihstatus" class="pilihstatus">
```

Then, get the corresponding id using the script below:

```
$(".pilihstatus").change(function(){

    var elem = $(this),
        selecteditem = elem.val(),
        id = elem.closest('tr').attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"updatestatustransaksi.php",
        data: {'status':selecteditem, 'id':id},
        success:function(data){
            alert('Successfully updated mysql database');
        }
    });
});
```

And on your updatestatustransaksi.php file (please use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)):

```
$stmt = $koneksi->prepare("UPDATE `konf_transf` SET `status` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $_POST['selecteditem'], $_POST['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: i change as you write here and in console I getting "TypeError: elem.nodeName is undefined", im using this jquery 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialised `$penjualan_id`? I think you need to initialise it like this:

```
$penjualan_id=$_SESSION['user_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding data_id  attribute to select

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>User ID</th>
         <th>Pengirim</th>
         <th>Jumlah Transfer</th>
         <th>Berita Acara</th>
         <th>Status</th>
         <th>Rincian</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <?php
         $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "select * from konf_transf order by tanggal desc limit 7 ");
         while($data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            ?>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <center><?php echo $data1['usr_id']; ?></center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center><?php echo $data1['nm_pengirim']; ?></center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>Rp. <?php echo number_format($data1['jmlh_transf'],0,'','.'); ?>,-</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center><?php echo $data1['berita_acara']; ?></center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center><?php echo $data1['status']; ?></center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>
               <select name="pilihstatus" id="pilihstatus" onchange="updatetransactions();" data_id='<?php echo $data1['usr_id']; ?>'>
                  <option value="Pilihan">Pilihan</option>
                  <option value="Sudah">Sudah</option>
                  <option value="Belum">Belum</option>
               </select>
            </center>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and get that data_id value in your function

```
function updatetransactions(){
  var status = $('select option:selected').text();
  var status = $('select').attr('data_id');
  var id = $('select option:selected').val();  
$.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"updatestatustransaksi.php",
            data:{'status'=status,'id'=id}
            success:function(data){
                alert('Successfully updated mysql database');
            }
        });
    }
```

and at your updatestatustransaksi.php

```
  <?php
require_once("koneksi.php");
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "<script>alert('You must register an account first, we will redirect you to register page !'); window.location = 'registuser.php'</script>";
}
$dataupd = $_POST["status"];
$id = $_POST["id"];
$query   = mysqli_query($koneksi, "UPDATE `konf_transf` SET `status` = '$dataupd' WHERE `id` = '$id'");
if ($query) {
    echo "<script>alert('Update Success.'); window.location = 'transactions.php' </script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Update Failure.'); window.location = 'transactions.php' </script>";
}
```